# Keycloak secure only specific routes [Client Side]

Tags: reactjs, react-router, openid-connect, keycloak

I have implemented keycloak authentication with my ReactJS application. Currenly all my routes are secured in the following way.

```
keyCloak.init({
    onLoad: 'login-required',
    checkLoginIframe: false
}).success(authenticated => {
    if (authenticated) {
        ReactDOM.render(Application, document.getElementById('root'));
    }
});
```

I render the react application only on authentication success. But now I need to have some public paths which doesn't need keycloak authentication where any user can go and check. Is there any proper way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Install @react-keycloak/web library

Pre requires: keycloak-js 9.0.2 or later

```
npm install --save keycloak-js
npm install --save @react-keycloak/web
```

Create a `keycloak.js` file in the `src` folder of your project with the following content to set up a Keycloak instance as needed.

Set up a Keycloak instance

```
import Keycloak from 'keycloak-js'
const keycloakConfig = {
  url: 'http://localhost:8080/auth', 
  realm: 'Demo', 
  clientId: 'react-app'
}
const keycloak = new Keycloak(keycloakConfig);
export default keycloak
```

Then Wrap your App inside `KeycloakProvider` and pass the `keycloak` instance as prop

```
import React from 'react';
import { KeycloakProvider } from '@react-keycloak/web'
import keycloak from './keycloak'
import AppRouter from './routes'

const App = () => {
  return (
    <KeycloakProvider keycloak={keycloak}>
      <AppRouter/>
    </KeycloakProvider>
  )
}
```

As you see in AppRouter component `useKeycloak` is being used without 1st param because we don't need that keycloak instance object to be used. But 2nd `initialized` parameter is being used because `PrivateRoute` is using keycloak instance, and keycloak object need to be available on `PrivateRoute` initialization, that means until keycloak initialized Routes cannot be returned

```
import { useKeycloak } from '@react-keycloak/web';

import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

import Menu from '../components/Menu';
import HomePage from '../pages/HomePage';
import { PrivateRoute } from '../utilities/PrivateRoute';
import ProtectedPage from '../pages/ProtectedPage';


export const AppRouter = () => {
    const [, initialized] = useKeycloak();
    if (!initialized) {
        return <h3>Loading ... !!!</h3>;
    }
    return (<>
        <Menu />
        <BrowserRouter>
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/" component={HomePage} />
                <PrivateRoute roles={['RealmAdmin']} path="/protected" component={ProtectedPage} />
            </Switch>
        </BrowserRouter>
    </>
    );
};
```

Create a `PrivateRoute.js` file in `src/utilities` folder of your project with the following content.

```
import { useKeycloak } from '@react-keycloak/web';
import React from 'react';
import { Redirect, Route } from 'react-router-dom';


export function PrivateRoute({ component: Component, roles, ...rest }) {
  const [keycloak] = useKeycloak();

  const isAutherized = (roles) => {
    if (keycloak && roles) {
        return roles.some(r => {
            const realm =  keycloak.hasRealmRole(r);
            const resource = keycloak.hasResourceRole(r);
            return realm || resource;
        });
    }
    return false;
   }

   return (
      <Route
        {...rest}
        render={props => {
            return isAutherized(roles)
                ? <Component {...props} />
                : <Redirect to={{ pathname: '/', }} />
        }}
      />
    )
}
```

Let’s see how to restrict Components/Functions with a Keycloak.

```
import { useKeycloak } from '@react-keycloak/web';




    export default function AuthorizedFunction(roles) {
        const [keycloak, initialized] = useKeycloak();

        const isAutherized = () => {
            if (keycloak && roles) {
                return roles.some(r => {
                    const realm =  keycloak.hasRealmRole(r);
                    const resource = keycloak.hasResourceRole(r);
                    return realm || resource;
                });
            }
            return false;
        }

        return isAutherized();
    }
```

[image]

Also, there is another way of restrict with anther wrapper component as below example. (with wrapper component)

https://medium.com/@cagline/authenticate-and-authorize-react-routes-component-with-keycloak-666e85662636

Comment: I followed your 'tutorial' but does it also implement the actual 'authentication', i.e. the forwarding to keycloak login? It looks like it does not, so how would you implement the `onLoad: 'login-required'`?

Answer (score 0):

You can create different roles in Keycloak. After authenticating in the React application, pass the Keycloak object in your application where you have the router with the paths. There you can check what permissions the user have and allow or not allow the routes based on it.

```
render() {
    let isAdmin = this.props.keycloak.hasRealmRole('admin');
    if(isAdmin){
        return (
            <div className="App">
                Router here
            </div>
        );
    }
    else{
        return (
            <div className="App">
                Router here
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Another option is to not wrap your whole application with Keycloak but only the components you are trying to secure.