# Optional authentication using Keycloak

Tags: javascript, reactjs, keycloak

Currently most of the React SPA applications I have, we require *authentication before user can access the site*, this is done using this inside the `index.js` when the app starts:

```
window.keycloak
  .init({
    onLoad: "login-required",
    checkLoginIframe: false,
    promiseType: "native",
  })
  .then((authenticated) => {
    ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
  })
  .catch(() => {
    console.error("failed to initialize");
  });
```

However, now I need to allow the user to be able to browse the site also in an *unauthenticated way* (authentication becomes optional basically). And only when user desires, then I have to redirect her to login page.

How can I do this using keycloak?

There is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51082435/keycloak-secure-only-specific-routes-client-side), but it is 5 years old and also the library which one of the answers seems to recommend seems to be deprecated. So I was wondering if there were better approaches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this issue a while ago.

Change the `onLoad` option to `"check-sso"` instead of `"login-required"`. This checks if the user is authenticated but won't force to log in.

```
onLoad: "check-sso",
```

Inside components use Keycloak to check if the user is authenticated and redirect to the login page.

```
import React from "react";

export default function ProtectedComponent(){
  if(!window.keycloak.authenticated){
    window.keycloak.login();
    return null;
  }
  return <div>U shall not pass</div>;
}
```